# Avoid audio to continue in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have an app where I play an audio-file on launch in the View Controller. I also have a button that switches to my second view. My problem is that the audio continues to play even after I have switched view. Here's my code for ViewController.m:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

//When I go to this view, I want the audio to stop
- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"home_sound"
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];

    NSError *error;
    homeaudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                   initWithContentsOfURL:url
                   error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
              [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        homeaudioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [homeaudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
        [homeaudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }

    [homeaudioPlayer play];

}


@end
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I solved it, by adding: [homeaudioPlayer stop]; to the SwitchView-function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update your SwitchView code-

```
- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
  [homeaudioPlayer stop];
  SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add [homeaudioPlayer stop]; to your switchView method. This should stop all sound that the player is playing.